# SassC::SyntaxError in Homepage#index

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I start the server using rails server from the root folder of my app. when I use localhost:3000 to view my homepage, it gives me this error (SassC::SyntaxError in Homepage#index). Why am I getting this error?

```
Showing /\[repo_name\]/app/views/homepage/index.html.erb where line # raised:
Error: no mixin named alert-variant
on line 27:14 of app/assets/stylesheets/admin/bootstrap-alert.scss

@include alert-variant($value, $value, $white);

-------------^
Extracted source (around line #27):

Fill alerts
.alert-fill-#{$state} {
**@include alert-variant($value, $value, $white);**
 &.alert-fill-light {
color: $text-muted;
}
```

---

With **@include alert-variant($value, $value, $white);** being marked red.

I'm using Ruby 3.2.2 / Rails 7.0.8 / Desktop Docker
Also Using Windows 10 with WSL installed

I looked at some online forums, and none of their solutions seem to help.

Sorry I'm very new to this and need some help!

Comment: Seems like the mixin `alert-variant` is missing.
I think the mixin should be included as part of the Bootstrap core CSS files. Did you include all of them in your project?

Comment: Did you import all of them in your project in the right order so that the mixin is declared before you try to `@include` it?

By the way, this person seems to have encountered the same problem: https://qiita.com/ayies128/items/83d04ca24b890b6308f4.

Sorry the article is in Japanese so please use Google Translate.

Comment: Turns out that the particular project I was working on had outdated bootstrap dependencies, and alert-variant was named differently. A simple change of version seemed to do the trick.
 Sorry for the late reply. I had completely forgotten about this case :)